# hibernate design issue

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a custom filter for querying the database.
The API layer build the filter,send it to the dao layer and the dao execute the filter (`filter.toCreteia()`) and return List of results.

```
public interface IFilter {
    Creteria toCriteria();
}
```

I want to make the DAO api to always as for filter + securityFilter in every method.

```
List getAll(IFilter filter, IFilter security); //each filter will be a creteria in the end
```

I end up inside the dao with 2 creterias: regular filter and security filter.
how can i render 2 creteias for returning one List of results?

Or, do you think I should use only one filter and in the API layer add security content to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to go with an interceptor approach (e.g., have a SecurityInterceptor/proxy class which transparently modifies the criteria) I think it would be nicer design to have two separate filters.

Note that I don't see that it is possible to join two `DetachedCriteria` objects together. Although you can have a routine which based on two `IFilter` objects returns a single `DetachedCriteria` based e.g. on `Restrictions.and(criterion1, criterion2)`.

Comment: Thanks, I have added add(Ifilter filter) to my interfase. inside i have joined 2 List<Criterion> which is possible. thanks